# Get ID from another table through a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry for Title, don't know how to explain.

[image]

Ok so I want to see if any protocol (PTC_ID) is linked to an Audit (AUD_ID), in the picture you can see there is 3 tables and each one has a value of the other.

I though of using `inner join` all 3 tables with the `ON` , `ON ADA_PTCID = PTC_ID` etc. and if a audit is linked with a `PTC` then display year?

Comment: what should be the output columns?

Comment: just the `PTC_ID` , `AUD_ID` and `AUD_YEAR`. that way I can see if a protocol is linked to a audit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
select
    ptc.ptc_name,
    aud.aud_year
from
    ptc_table ptc
inner join
    ada_table ada
on
    ada.ada_ptcid=ptc.ptc_id
inner join
    aud_table aud
on
    aud.aud_id=ada.ada_aud_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select AUD_YEAR
From AUD_Table at
Inner Join ADA_TABLE ad
   ON at.AUD_ID = ad.ADA_AUD_ID
Inner Join PTC_TABLE pt
   ON pt.PTC_ID=ad.ADA_PTCID
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
    select 
    aud.year,ptc.name 
    from ada 
    inner join aud on ada.aud_id = aud.aud_id 
    inner join ptc on ada.ptc_id = ptc.ptc_id
```